# Get an array of strings instead of objects in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have this Sequelize Model named Recipe where I need to make a join from Model Diet, but I get an array of objects with only the property I want, but I would like to get it as a string, not an object.

```
const dbDataTest = await Recipe.findAll({

    include: [
      {
        model: Diet,
        attributes: {
            exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'id']
        },
        through: {attributes: []}
      },
    ],
});
```

That's why I'm excluding 3 other attributes so I can get only this output:

```
{
Recipe name: 'Name',
diets: ['diet one', 'diet two']
}
```

instead, I'm Getting:

```
{
Recipe name: 'Name',
diets:[
        {name: 'diet one'},
        {name: 'diet two'}
      ]
}
```

Comment: I think this may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65298661/10213537

Comment: @Ameer Thanks, I already implemented a map but I wanted to know if there was a way to do it with sequelize